# facing ERROR [+1019] extracting mfcc features using the HCopy of HTK toolkit

Tags: audio, htk

I'm new to htk. Trying to extract some mfcc features from a bunch of .wav files.
facing ERROR [+1019]

Here is my confing (config_mfcc.cfg) file:

```
SOURCEFORMAT = WAV
TARGETKIND = MFCC_E_D_A
TARGETRATE = 100000.0
NUMCEPS = 13
USEHAMMING = T
PREEMCOEF = 0.97
NUMCHANS = 26
CEPLIFTER = 22
NUMFILTERS = 40
```

Here is my script (extract_features_path.scp):

```
C:\my_data_directory\*.wav
```

Here is the shell command and the error:

```
C:\some_direcory>HCopy -T 1 -C config_mfcc.cfg -S extract_features_path.scp
  ERROR [+1019]  HCopy: Target file or + operator expected
 FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HCopy
```